# How to hide the inactive products from in app billing?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

We have an android app supporting In App Billing v3. In our tests, everything else worked fine, but we found that inactive products could also be obtained by querying the inventory.

This is how we query our Google Play in app products inventory:

```
ArrayList<String> moreSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
moreSkus.add("gas");
moreSkus.add("premium");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, moreSkus, mGotInventoryListener);

...

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, final Inventory inventory) {
        if(inventory.hasDetails("premium")) {
            System.out.println("Inactive product is also visible to app!");
        }
    }
};
```

Among the two products, "premium" is inactive, but the print statement in IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener was still executed!

Is there a way to get active products only?

Comment: if you know that premium is inactive, why do you query it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can remove the sku from the query list

```
//moreSkus.add("premium"); //don't query this item
```

This depends on your code but kinda makes sense, since you cannot query all available products with an empty "moreSku" list, you have to choose what you really want; it depends on your code anyway.
Hope it can help.